# Finding nth permutation for parallelized C/C++

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, parallel-processing, mpi

I am currently looking for a way to find the nth permutation of an array in lexicographic order by using a function. I have a sequential code that was written using `next_permutation` from the C++ libraries (the rest of the code is plain old C) but due to the way that `next_permutation` works, it is not only inefficient but also extremely difficult to use in a parallelized version of the code. I am using Open MPI so that each process is having to use `next_permutation` and the math gets very confusing at this point. Also, `next_permutation` calculates up to n every time, so that each process has to do many more calculations than should be necessary. I've heard of using a factoradic in order to find the nth permutation but I have been unable to find any information on its use. Is there a function in the C/C++ libraries that give the factoradic, or is there a good resource I could find that does this? Is there any better way to find the nth permutation of a specific array?

For example:

array[3] = {1, 2, 3}

factoradicFunc(3) --> 2, 1, 3

factoradicFunc(4) --> 2, 3, 1

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've posted the following example elsewhere, but let me repeat it here:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef char           element_t;
typedef unsigned long  permutation_t;

static permutation_t factorial(const permutation_t n)
{
    permutation_t i, result = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        const permutation_t  newresult = result * i;
        if ((permutation_t)(newresult / i) != result)
            return 0;
        result = newresult;
    }
    return result;
}

int permutation(element_t *const        buffer,
                const element_t *const  digits,
                const size_t            length,
                permutation_t           index)
{
    permutation_t  scale;
    size_t         i, d;

    if (!buffer || !digits || length < 1)
        return errno = EINVAL;

    scale = factorial(length);
    if (!scale)
        return errno = EMSGSIZE;
    if (index >= scale)
        return errno = ENOENT;

    /* Copy original ordered set to mutable buffer */     
    memmove(buffer, digits, length * sizeof (element_t));

    for (i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        scale /= (permutation_t)(length - i);
        d = index / scale;
        index %= scale;
        if (d > 0) {
            const element_t c = buffer[i + d];
            memmove(buffer + i + 1, buffer + i, d * sizeof (element_t));
            buffer[i] = c;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The `factorial()` function is just a slow but careful implementation of the [factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). Since 13! > 2<sup>32</sup>, 21! > 2<sup>64</sup>, and 35! > 2<sup>128</sup>, there are only a very few possible results for 32, 64, or 128-bit unsigned integer `permutation_t` types, it would be better to simply use an array lookup for the factorials instead (as [rcgldr already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33984186/1475978)).

The `permutation(buffer, digits, length, index)` function takes a target `buffer` of length `length`, and fills it with the `index`'th permutation of `digits`. (The `digits` is read-only, immutable.)

This is not the fastest possible implementation, but it will calculate any permutation in `O(length)` time complexity (ignoring the `memmove()` operation; `O(length²)` if you consider the `memmove()`). It is sub-optimal, because it uses `memmove()` to reorder the items in the target `buffer`, and requires two divisions (and one modulus with the same divisor) per element.

Considering the maximum practical length limitations (12, 20, or 34 elements, depending on the size of the `permutation_t` type), the use of `memmove()` is not an issue (because the data is within one or at most a couple of cache lines).

This is thread-safe, as long as only one thread operates on the same target `buffer` at the same time; multiple threads generating different target `buffer`s from the same source `digits` buffer is thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a table of factorials. If using 64 bit unsigned integers, the maximum value is 20! = 2432902008176640000, or for 32 bit unsigned integers, the max is 12! = 479001600, so the table is small.

A prior thread in the math section:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60742/finding-the-n-th-lexicographic-permutation-of-a-string